# SQL SERVER | Preencher campos vazios no select

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho um select em uma tabela:

```
select a.linha, a.NUM_LCTO, a.DT_LCTO from arquivo a order by 1
```

Que me retorna os valores da seguinte forma (coloquei apenas algumas linhas, o resultado total são cerca de 800000 linhas.):

```html
linha       NUM_LCTO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         DT_LCTO
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9544        7627367-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9545                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9546                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9547        7627371-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9548                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9549                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9550        7627373-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9551                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9552                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9553        7627374-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9554                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9555                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9556                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9557                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9558        7627375-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9559                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9560                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9561        7627376-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9562                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9563                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
9564
```

Preciso preencher as colunas vazias de "NUM_LCTO" e "DT_LCTO", com o valor das linhas preenchidas, respeitando as respectivas mudanças de valores.
O resultado deve ser semelhante a isso:

```html
linha       NUM_LCTO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         DT_LCTO
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9544        7627367-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9545        7627367-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9546        7627367-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9547        7627371-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9548        7627371-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9549        7627371-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9550        7627373-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9551        7627373-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9552        7627373-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9553        7627374-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9554        7627374-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9555        7627374-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9556        7627374-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9557        7627374-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9558        7627375-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9559        7627375-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9560        7627375-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9561        7627376-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9562        7627376-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9563        7627376-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
9564        7627376-0101                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     01012018
```

Alguém pode ajudar?
Tentei montar o campo com subquery, mas em determinado momento ele se perde e não bagunça os códigos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize um `OUTER APPLY` na mesma tabela para selecionar o último registro preenchido antes do que você deseja:

```
SELECT a.linha,
       CASE ISNULL(a.num_lcto, '') WHEN '' THEN ref.num_lcto ELSE a.num_lcto END AS num_lcto
  FROM arquivo a
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) a2.linha,
                  a2.num_lcto
      FROM arquivo a2
     WHERE a2.linha < a.linha
       AND ISNULL(a2.num_lcto, '') <> ''
     ORDER BY a2.linha DESC
  ) ref
```

Resultando em:

```
linha   | num_lcto
----------------------
9544    | 7627367-0101
9545    | 7627367-0101
9546    | 7627367-0101
9547    | 7627371-0101
9548    | 7627371-0101
9549    | 7627371-0101
9550    | 7627373-0101
9551    | 7627373-0101
9552    | 7627373-0101
9553    | 7627374-0101
9554    | 7627374-0101
9555    | 7627374-0101
9556    | 7627374-0101
9557    | 7627374-0101
9558    | 7627375-0101
9559    | 7627375-0101
9560    | 7627375-0101
9561    | 7627376-0101
9562    | 7627376-0101
9563    | 7627376-0101
9564    | 7627376-0101
```

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c0311/1).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, para as 800000 linhas precisei criar um índice "clustered" para melhorar a performance um pouco, não sei se dá pra melhorar mais, mas já deu uma ajuda. Valeu!

Answer (score -2):

Como é um select vc nao poderá preencher os campos vazios. Justamente pq é um select.
Vc tera que fazer um select de todos as linhas com os campos vazios da tabela, alterar para o valor que vc quer e fazer o update e depois fazer o select denovo.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/228791)

Comment: O OUTER APPLY funciona no SQL SERVER e no MySQL tbm?